# Sylow's theorem for group of $2$ by $2$ matrices of determinant $1$ over the field of order $3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $G=SL(2,\mathbb{F_3})$ - group of $2$ by $2$ matrices of determinant $1$ over the field of order $3$.

> (a) Find the order of $G$.

I think it is $24$ but not sure how to verify it.

> (b) Show that $Z(G) \neq \{1_G\}$.

$Z(G) = \{g \in G\ |\ gh=hg\ \forall\ h \in G\}$ Something to do with matrices not being commutative (when multiplied).

> (c) Determine the number of Sylow $3$-subgroups of $G$.

$r \equiv 1 \pmod3$ but not sure how to calculate the number.

> (d) What is the isomorphism type of a Sylow $3$-subgroup of $G$?

Can I just state this?

> (e) Determine the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups of $G$.

I said $8$ but not sure how to explain it.

> (f) What is the isomorphism type of a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$?

$Q_8$. How can I justify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) You are correct in that the order of $G$ is $24$. Here's a strategy for proving it:

First find the order of $GL(2,\mathbb{F}_3)$. The first row of your matrix can be any nonzero vector, so you have $(3^2 - 1)$ choices. The second row can then be any vector outside the span of the first row vector, so you have $(3^2 - 3)$ choices, hence the order of $GL(2, \mathbb{F}_3)$ is $(3^2 - 1)(3^2 - 3) = 48$.

Now all matrices in $GL(2, \mathbb{F}_3)$ have determinant $1$ or $2$. Show that there is a bijection between matrices of determinant $1$ or $2$ and hence $$\vert G \vert = \frac{\vert GL(2, \mathbb{F}_3) \vert}{2}$$

(b) Since the field is $\mathbb{F}_3$, we have $I \neq -I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, and it is easy to show that $-I \in Z(G)$, hence $Z(G) \neq \{1_G\}$. You can also show using just the definitions that $Z(G) = \{\pm I\}$ (let $A \in Z(G)$, then $AB = BA$ for all $B \in G$, then set up matrix equations).

(c) Let $n_3$ be the number of $3$-Sylow subgroups of $G$. The Sylow theorems will tell you that $n_3 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ and $n_3$ divides $24$. Therefore $n_3$ is $1$ or $4$. So if you can find two order $3$ subgroups of $G$, you can can conclude $n_3 = 4$.

(d) I would say that a $3$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ has order $3$, and the only group of order $3$ up to isomorphism is $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. How much you have to say depends on context.

(e) It is not $8$. The order of a $2$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ is $8$. Again the Sylow theorems tell you that $n_2 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ and $n_2$ divides $24$. So $n_2 = 1$ or $3$. Suppose $n_2 = 3$. Let the $2$-sylow subgroups be $H_1,H_2,H_3$. Show that $G/\{\pm I\} \cong A_4$, which has a normal order $4$ subgroup $V_4$. All of the elements of $H_1,H_2,H_3$ must be mapped into $V_4$ by the projection map $\pi : G \to G/\{\pm I\}$. Use this to show that $\vert \cup_{i=1}^{3} H_i \vert = 8$, hence $n_2 = 1$.

(f) Argue that the $2$-Sylow subgroup $P_2$ of $G$ is non-abelian and that the unique element of order $2$ is $-I$. This is enough to imply that $P_2 \cong Q_8$ (you will probably want to verify this).

Comment: For your bijection question, let $X$ be the set of matrices in $G$ with determinant $1$, and $Y$ be the set of matrices in $G$ with determinant $2$. Then the map $f : A \to B$ defined by $f(X) = MX$, where $M$ is any matrix in $G$ of determinant $2$, is a bijection.

A group of order $3$ is cyclic so it must the group consisting of powers of those matrices.

Comment: And I agree indeed that the way you linked is better than mine. The number of elements of orders powers of $2,3$ follows from counting the number of elements in the sylow subgroups and noting that any element in a $p$ sylow subgroup must have order a power of $p$.

To see there is a unique order $2$ element, set up the matrix equation $A^2 = I$ and deduce that $A = -I$ or $I$. Also it cannot be $D_8$ because $D_8$ has five elements of order $2$.

Comment: For the # of elements in the $2$-Sylow subgroups: think about it like this: Suppose there are three $2$-Sylow subgroups $H_1, H_2, H_3$. Then there intersection has size at most $4$, so there are at least $(8 - 4) * 3 + 4$ elements in their union. The $+4$ is so that we count the elements in the intersection once.

You cannot take nay two elements of $G$, you must take two elements of $G$ in the $2$-sylow subgroup.

Comment: Those elements should e fine. The intersection is a subgroup so it has to have size $1,2,4,8$. But if it has size $8$, that would imply that they are all the same, i.e. there is only one $2$-sylow subgroup, a contradiction.

Comment: Many thanks for your help.